# return the maximum number of num and ordersource concatenated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
create table test(id int ,num numeric(10),[Ordersource] varchar(10)) 
insert into test (id,num,[Order])values(1,10,'s1'),(1,10,'s2'),(1,10,'s3'),(1,10,'s4'),(1,12,'s5'),(1,12,'s6'),(2,13,'s6')
```

I want output Format is

```
id num ordersource
1 10   s1,s2,s3,s4
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Your result set does not make ANY sense!!!

Comment: And then, what is the expectation for the outputs?

Comment: Sorry , A table has three columns id,num ,order  the id and num columns are  repeated one in the table and the order source are different I want the result set to remove the duplicate as each id wants to return the maximum occurrence of number and their order in comma separated .

Comment: i need to concatenate the order values for each id uniquely for the maximum occurrence of the number  i.e here for id  1 it has to return number 10 alone the output has to be 1 10 s1,s2,s3,s4 it should not return 12 as 10 is maximum occurence.

Comment: It's usually better to do such formatting at a higher layer than SQL - SQL is oriented around tables with columns, where each column (in a particular row) contains a *single* value.

Comment: +1 for supplying DDL commands and inserts of test data.

Answer (score 4):

Hope this will help

```
Declare @test table (id int ,num numeric(10),[Order] varchar(10)) 
Insert into @test (id,num,[Order])
Values(1,10,'s1'),(1,10,'s2'),(1,10,'s3'),(1,10,'s4'),(1,12,'s5'),(1,12,'s6'),(2,13,'s6')

;With Cte As
(
    Select 
        X.* 
        ,rn=Dense_Rank()over(order by cnt desc)
    From (
    Select  
        id
        , num
        ,ordersource = Stuff((
            Select ',' + Cast([Order] As Varchar(Max))
            From @test t2 
            Where t1.id = t2.id and t1.num = t2.num
            For Xml Path('')
         ),1,1,'')
        ,cnt = count(num) over(partition by id, num)        
    From @test t1)X
)
Select distinct id, num,ordersource
From Cte
Where rn = 1
```

[image]

Comment: tanx, the result has to be as 1 10 s1,s2,s3,s4 it shouldnt return 12 bcoz my scenario is that it has to return only the maximum occurence.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach:

```
select id, num, left(s, len(s) - 1)
from (
    select distinct t2.id, t2.num, (
        select t1.O + ', ' as 'text()'
        from test t1
        where t1.id = t2.id and t1.num = t2.num
        order by t1.id, t1.num
        for xml path('')) s
    from test t2) temp
where
    id = 1
    and num = 10
```