# Getting CSV list in a column, keeping a column distinct (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help writing an SQL Query which would get me the results as I want.

I have a document upload feature, in which a document can be upload for clients on multiple locations. The table structure is simple, there are just 5 columns; FileID, FileName, Title, Description and LocationID.
If a user uploads a document for 3 locations, 3 entries are entered in to this table. Lets say

```
FileID FileName    Title      Description      LocationID
1      File1       File1      Description 1    100
2      File1       File1      Description 1    21
4      File1       File1      Description 1    181
```

A user uploads another file for 4 locations, the data gets entered and the table now looks like this

```
FileID FileName    Title      Description      LocationID
1      File1.doc   File1      Description 1    100
2      File1.doc   File1      Description 1    21
4      File1.doc   File1      Description 1    181
5      File2.pdf   File2      Description 2    123
6      File2.pdf   File2      Description 2    12
7      File2.pdf   File2      Description 2    126
8      File2.pdf   File2      Description 2    100
```

Now what i want in the result is

```
FileName    Title      Description      LocationCSV
File1.doc   File1      Description 1    100, 21, 181
File2.pdf   File2      Description 2    123, 12, 126, 100
```

Comment: Ofcourse, I searched a lot. Tried using COALESCE but didnt help.

Comment: I am using ms sql server

Comment: TODAY there was an [answer to question like yours](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13874671/return-the-maximum-number-of-num-and-ordersource-concatenated)

Comment: Which sql server version? 2005+ nas FOR XML PATH - use this

Comment: @Valex but look at the answer below, could it be more simpler than this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In SQL Server you can use `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FileName,
  Title,
  Description,
  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cast(LocationID as varchar(20))
         from yourtable m
         where p.FileName = m.FileName
         group by LocationID, fileid
         order by fileid
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'') LocationCSV
from yourtable p
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4add/5)

Or another version using `FOR XML PATH`:

```
SELECT FileName,
  Title,
  Description, LEFT(LocationCSV , LEN(LocationCSV)-1) LocationCSV
FROM yourtable p
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT cast(LocationID as varchar(20)) + ','
    FROM yourtable m
    WHERE p.FileName = m.FileName
    FOR XML PATH('')
) m (LocationCSV)
group by FileName, Title, Description, LocationCSV
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a4add/13)

Result:

```
|  FILENAME | TITLE |   DESCRIPTION |        LOCATIONCSV |
----------------------------------------------------------
| File1.doc | File1 | Description 1 |       100, 21, 181 |
| File2.pdf | File2 | Description 2 |  123, 12, 126, 100 |
```

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

```
select FileName,
       Title,
       Description, 
       group_concat(LocationID) as  LocationCSV 
from t group by FileName,Title,Description
```

Comment: +1 didn't know about `group_concat`. Thanks. I'll have to check if SQL Server has something like this.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the answer of Bradc. I like this method to concat columns.

[Simulating group_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)